# ImportError: cannot import name 'compile'

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I'm trying to install python 3.4 and TensorFlow on my Mac (OSX El Capitan version 10.11.1).
I am following the instructions here

[Pip Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/get_started/os_setup.html#pip_install)

I can do

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade six
```

but then this part gets difficult:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

I put in my password;
it gives me a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2859, in _dep_map
return self.__dep_map
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2696, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3138, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3124, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3151, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 661, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 962, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 857, in resolve
new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2640, in requires
dm = self._dep_map
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2861, in _dep_map
self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2878, in _compute_dependencies
from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
ImportError: cannot import name 'compile'
```

Did I miss any important information?

Comment: Please edit your posting and use code formatting for your stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: FYI TensorFlow from [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) is at version 0.6.0 and the Python wheel you are trying to install is at 0.5.0. If you want the newer version you will need to build from [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/get_started/os_setup.html#installation-for-mac-os-x).

Comment: have you tried downloading the .wheel file and installing from local?

Comment: After reading [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35077111/1243762) by mrry I looked for the  OS X py3 pip install wheel for TensorFlow 0.6.0 link and found it on the GitHub site's [Download and Setup page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md)  -  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for this error is that the package you are trying to install is a *Python 2* wheel file. (The `py2` in the URL is the clue to this Moreover, as Guy Coder points out in the comments, you're installing version 0.5.0 of TensorFlow, which did not support Python 3.)

The best solution would be to install the [Python 3–compatible package](http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl):

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

(It appears that these links aren't easy to find on the website, so we'll fix that shortly.)

Comment: Thanks. I did not think to check other locations for links to other versions, e.g. GitHub.

Comment: Well I tried that TensorFlow version 0.6.0, and it gave me the same error.
So I checked my python version using 
$ python --version
and it gave me python 2.7, which confused me greatly.

I then went to the above directory: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
and checked again, no luck.
I eventually installed python 3.4 again, 64 bit.
Then found that I needed to ask which version with this command:
python3 --version
which gave Python 3.4.4rc1.
Then I went into python3 using that command "python3", tried to 
import tensorflow
IT WORKED! Thanks! :-) :-)